# Can't localize info.plist strings

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, info.plist

I need to localize two keys of info.plist: `NSLocationUsageDescription` and `NSCameraUsageDescription`. So I tried to create a new file called InfoPlist.strings and then I localized it, but app always shows strings stored in info.plist file. What's wrong?

Official documentation from [Information Property List Key Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html)

> Localized values are not stored in the Info.plist file itself.
>   Instead, you store the values for a particular localization in a
>   strings file with the name InfoPlist.strings. You place this file in
>   the same language-specific project directory that you use to store
>   other resources for the same localization. The contents of the
>   InfoPlist.strings file are the individual keys you want localized and
>   the appropriately translated value. The routines that look up key
>   values in the Info.plist file take the user’s language preferences
>   into account and return the localized version of the key (from the
>   appropriate InfoPlist.strings file) when one exists. If a localized
>   version of a key does not exist, the routines return the value stored
>   in the Info.plist file.

My InfoPlist.strings file:

```
NSCameraUsageDescription = "hello";
NSLocationUsageDescription = "hello hello";
```

Comment: Did you change the language of iPhone simulator? Change from the Settings app, not from the scheme.

Comment: Use InfoPlist.strings http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25736700/how-to-localise-a-string-inside-the-ios-info-plist-file

Answer (score 15):

Please check in the generated application package, whether the file is really stored in there and it is put to the correct location. Usually this is the missing step.

Just go into the project settings, open "Build Phases" and see whether
 the file can be found in "Copy Bundle Resources"

Comment: Good point! For me InfoPlist.string was ignored until I manually added it to Copy Bundle Resources

Answer (score 7):

Your plist file can have multiple versions for each language your application supports. 
In Utilities \ File Inspector (on the right) click on "Localize":

[image]

And then choose the languages you want to have their own versions:

[image]

After that you will be able to enter each plist file and edit it as you want.

Comment: ok, I have file named "someinfo.plist" which works as "info.plist" but need to be specified in project settings (section "Packaging"). How to specify a path to it when it is localized?

Comment: It's automatically. for each language youe app will use the relevant plist. if there isn't one (there isn't a plist file for current language) - your app will use the basic one.

Answer (score 7):

`InfoPlist.strings` doesn't consider your scheme's Application Region, but the region set in the device! On your device: `Settings`**->** `General` **->** `Language & Region`, check if iPhone Language is the one that you like.

Comment: Yep, this is important for sure!

Answer (score 3):

Since iOS 10, you are required to add the privacy keys to your Info.plist.

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>Please allow access to the photo library.</string>
```

Of course, you still need those keys to be localized (and you can't localize the application's Info.plist). So you ALSO add those privacy keys to the InfoPlist.strings, which in turn are localized.

```
"NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription" = "Please allow access to the photo library.";
```

Answer (score 2):

As a matter of fact, my problem was that I had misspelled the NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription constant so of course it was not taken into account.

Comment: haha, just wanted to comment the same: had a typo in a word, check the word letter by letter

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you have to make a Clean first, Click Menu -> Product -> Clean.

[image: Sometimes you have to make a Clean first]

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was a conflict with other InfoPlist.strings file from another build target.

Answer (score 0):

After double checking everything said in this thread, my last action was deleting the app and its' data then re-run/re-install it to Simulator and my localization worked for Info.plist

One more thing, I made the simulator main language the testing language I want (Arabic), and to change that in the simulator Settings>General>Language

Answer (score -1):

The file needs to be inside of a directory indicating the language, for example en.lproj

Answer (score -2):

It depends on your iPhone or iPad ‘s language, it will automatically pick the description from the "InfoPlist.strings" file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).