# How to localize NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription from Info.plist file in xamarin.iOS?

Tags: localization, xamarin.ios, info.plist

My application includes feature related to location tracking. I am trying to localize `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` string from Info.plist file.

As described in link below, I have added InfoPlist.strings file in en.Iproj and for localization InfoPlist.Stings file in de.Iproj. Added Localizations array (supported languages) in Info.Plist. Set "Localized resources can be mixed" to "Yes".

[Xamarin.iOS localization of NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26175820/xamarin-ios-localization-of-nslocationwheninuseusagedescription).

Tested the app by changing language of device and simulator both. However, no success. It just displays default language message.

Please let me know what I am missing to add.

Comment: Not Info.strings-- name of string file must be InfoPlist.strings

Comment: Sorry, My mistake. It is InfoPlist.strings. However, still no success.