# IOS 8 NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription custom translation

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, localization, ios8

I understood that I can have localized NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription text using standard iOS localization mechanism.
Since we are using our custom dynamic localisation mechanism I wonder if there is another way to translate that string.
I thought of editing application info.plist file on app start, but it seems to be read only.

Can I change this value from withing the app?

Comment: try to COPY the info.plist file in different ".lprj" folders ... and change the message accordingly

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's *no way* to use a **custom localisation system** with the info.plist strings.

That part of your app will have to use *iOS's default localisation mechanism*.

This is how to localise the location request description with iOS's built in strings file localisation system.

```
// English.strings file
"NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription" = "English description";

// AnotherLanguage.strings
"NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription" = "ajbdknfuied wibnrf";
```

**EDIT:** At everyone down voting me. The question asked about using a custom "custom localisation system". They explicitly said they did not want to use the built in localisation system, but instead their own custom one. That is why I said it was impossible.

Localising `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` is completely possible. Using your own custom localisation system to do it is not.

Comment: Actually there is. Please check my answer.

Comment: Also, sometimes it's easier to check the official documentation. Paragraph "Localizing Property List Values" https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html

Answer (score 13):

There is a way. Add a new Strings file called "InfoPlist". Then localize it  using a Localize button in attributes inspector and add localizations to the InfoPlist's keys. To localize CLLocation premission's description add in every version proper key and loacalised value.

```
//English file
"NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription" = "English description";
```

_

```
//Polish file
"NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription" = "Polski opis";
```

Comment: That's exactly what I do not want to do - I do not want to use standard localization mechanism.

Comment: This is correct but just a duplicate, Kyle Howells already provided the correct answer.

Comment: @Misha if you don't want to use the standard, find a way to override the content of the info.plist at build time, but you need multiple targets for country/language, which I really hope you don't have.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using the answers above, but had no luck until I used the information in [this much more helpful thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25736700/how-to-localise-a-string-inside-the-ios-info-plist-file).