# How to Localize Location Permission Dialog alert?

Tags: ios, swift, app-store-connect, itunes

My app have been rejected by apple because the message in `Grant Location Permissions` is not clear. My app has two language(English, Vietnamese). How do I create localised messages for both Vietnamese and English users?

Comment: you may check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33423565/2450755

Comment: Have you internationalised the info.plist file?