# Localizing iOS Location Permission Prompt

Tags: ios, localization, core-location, info-plist

I have a localized app that needs to request user permission to access the device's location.  Since iOS 8, this requires a message (defined in `Info.plist`) stating *why* the app needs the user's location.  I have localized this message successfully, [using this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25736915/119114).  I have an InfoPlist.strings file with a foreign-language entry for the key `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription`:

```
"NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription" = "Este aplicativo pode utilizar a sua localização para servir anúncios que são mais relevantes. Sua identidade não é transmitida com a localização.";
```

This properly localizes the message explaining why the app needs user location.  But, when iOS shows the alert view containing this message, the **title** of the alert, and the **buttons** are not localized:

[image]

How do I localize the alert's title and button text, too?

I understand how to do all this for a `UIAlertView` that I show manually, but this alert is shown by the system (iOS).

Comment: It also strikes me that this *shouldn't* be my responsibility, and iOS should be localizing these messages itself. If the answer is "it's a bug", that's fine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Did you test on an actual device?  I believe the simulator has a bug but it works on real devices.

Comment: I'll check. Yes, the above was on a simulator.

Comment: Uuughh. Yep, it's a simulator bug. Real iOS 8.4 device localizes title and buttons just fine. Thanks for that.