# Info.plist and Base localization: Project not compiling

Tags: ios, xcode

After enabling Base locaization on the Info.plist, [Xcode bailed on me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35300593/xcode-crash-on-adding-localization-for-info-plist-with-base-localization).

Since then, it refuses to compile the project, stating

> could not read data from '/Users/[redacted]/git/[redacted]/[redacted]/Info.plist': The file “Info.plist” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.

Which does not surprise me, given that it now is in `/Users/[redacted]/git/[redacted]/[redacted]/Base.lproj/Info.plist`.

Moving the file back in the Filesystem yields

> /Users/[redacted]/git/[redacted]/[redacted]/Base.lproj/Info.plist:0: error: reading data: The file “Info.plist” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.

which rather surprises me.

How can one fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright.

It seems the localization process can be reversed by removing `Info.plist` from the project while in the project directory. Xcode didn't ask what to do with the original file because it couldn't find it.

Re-adding the file to the project by drag and drop (not copying obviously, because it is already there) made it compile.