# Can we localize the iOS app name dynamically

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, localization, cfbundledisplayname

I am developing an iOS framework (say xyz.framework) , in that I am trying to build a feature to localize the bundle display name (CFBundleDisplayName) where I should localize the app name (name of the app which consumes my xyz.framework)

As per my understanding we have to mention name of the app in infoPlist.Strings file and we should localize,

My question is can we pick the app name dynamically with out hardcoding it ? if yes how can I do it ?

Please help me out!

Comment: Take the first answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25736700/how-to-localise-a-string-inside-the-ios-info-plist-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the first answer to this question:

[How to localise a string inside the iOS info.plist file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25736700/how-to-localise-a-string-inside-the-ios-info-plist-file)

Since the name of the app needs to be localised **before** the app is running, it is obviously not possible to change it dynamically. I might download your app and never, ever run it.

Answer (score 0):

No, `Info.plist` values must be hardcoded and cannot be changed at runtime (this actually makes sense if you think about it).

The same applies to the localized version.