# iOS 10 and Permissions localization description

Tags: ios, permissions, xcode8, ios-permissions

Faced interesting thing while preparing app for iOS 10. Starting from Xcode 8 you must provide description about any permission you ask in the app (https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/49951)

Everything seems good, but what if I want localize this descriptions?

If I would place it inside `InfoPlist.strings` - app will continue crashing. But if I would place it in `InfoPlist.strings` and `Info.plist` - app would always take description from `Info.plist`, so there won't be any localization.

Maybe someone have a solution. Thanks :)

Comment: Checked it on device & simulator (Xcode 8 beta 5, iOS 10 beta 5) with `NSCameraUsageDescription` / `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription` - works as expected with placing strings only inside of `InfoPlist.strings`. Which usage description are you trying to localize?

Comment: It seems that the problem in quotes around the key. Try `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription = "Value";`

Comment: @RomanErmolov problem in video was about copying key from stackoverflow (there was strange symbol between key prefix and description), so it works now. Checking my key

Comment: @RomanErmolov checked with Xcode 8 beta 6 in fresh project, everything work fine. Can't launch working project right now, but if there will be a problem, it would relate to this project itself. Thank you for the help!

Comment: the localization strings work well on iOS11, but not on iOS10. don't know why

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I faced the same issue and I was able to resolve it because I noticed that the `InfoPlist.strings` wasn't member of any target.

So setting the `Target Membership` on the file (which puts it into the `Copy Bundle Resources` build phase) fixed it.

---

And for anyone googling here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html

Scroll down to "Localizing Property List Values"

Comment: thanks for that Martin - so, after I set `Target Membership`, indeed it then allows localization of the whole plist file ??  cheers...

Comment: Yes, you can put any `"key" = "string";` into the `InfoPlist.strings` of the respective language and it will be used instead of the value provided in the `Info.plist`. I suggest putting a default value in the `Info.plist` anyway even though from my experiment it was not necessary to put the key in the plist itself. Also the name of `InfoPlist.strings` is crucial as indicate the comments in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25736700/how-to-localise-a-string-inside-the-ios-info-plist-file .

Comment: Same problem, but my Info.strings files were already added to the target. Nevertheless, the text in the Info.plist was output.

Comment: @ReinhardMänner I suggest you double check the naming of the strings file and the name of the keys you are trying to localize.

Comment: @Martin Polak thank you! I made the crazy error to name these files "Info.strings" since the unlocalized version is named "Info.plist". After renaming them to "InfoPlist.strings" everything works as expected.

Comment: Please note that doc state that key should not be double quoted... `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription = "xxx";` vs `"NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription" = "xxx";`. i.e.: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html

Comment: Also, changing language using specific `scheme` doesn't seem to work correctly for `Info.plist` localization, you need to manually set the simulator language to see the localized text.

Comment: its not working, if I use this: NSLocalizedString(@"NSCameraUsageDescription",nil). It should work this way? Although OS is picking the right localization when it asks for permissions. But if I want to display this text somewhere, all I see is "NSCameraUsageDescription"

Answer (score 11):

Here are the steps for localizing info.plist variables

1. create a new file named "InfoPlist.strings" under your project
   [image: .string]
2. click on your project to open settings (if target is your app, select project by just clicking it in opened window)
   add any necessary languages under "localizations"
3. go to your InfoPlist.strings file and mark checkbox of desired languages under localizations. (Press "utilities" button unless localizations is not visible after clicking on .strings file, which is at the top right corner of xcode - the rightmost one)
   [image: localize]
4. add necessary "key" = "value" pairs for all localization languages in InfoPlist.strings. If you have difficulties in finding keys belonging to info.plist rows, just right click on your info.plist and select Open As -> Source Code, all row parameters are indicated as keys in source code

Comment: it's helpful.
https://daddycoding.com/2020/07/14/ios-tutorial-localization-permission-pop-up/

Answer (score 9):

[image]

[image]

Steps to Implement the localization for Permission.

Step 1 - Click the Info.plist

Step 2 - Click the Localize button [Xcode right middle]

Step 3 - Tick the languages

Comment: This is wrong answer. The question was about `.strings` files.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue, it was caused by using the wrong file name:

```
InfoPList.strings
```

instead of

```
InfoPlist.strings
```

Hope this info might be of useful for someone.

Comment: What is the difference betweeen this file names?

Comment: Difference is a typo in `InfoPlist`

Comment: The typo is a capital L in P(L)ist.

xCode requires exact name match. It needs to be InfoPlist.strings