# Can you localized NSAppleMusicUsageDescription?

Tags: ios, plist

Can you localize the following keys in your iOS app's .plist file?

- [`NSAppleMusicUsageDescription`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html)
- `NSCalendarsUsageDescription`
- `NSCameraUsageDescription`
- `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription`
- `NSMicrophoneUsageDescription`
- `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription`

Comment: If you paste those keys into the "Key" column when you create a new row in your `info.plist` - Xcode will handle them accordingly.. For instance when you paste in `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription`, it automatically converts it to "Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description", and then you put a custom description in the value column to show the user when requesting access to their photo library the first time.

Comment: Right -- but can that custom description be localized into different languages, or must it always be in one language (in my case, English?)

Comment: The full answer is found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25736700/how-to-localise-a-string-inside-the-ios-info-plist-file