# Missing Info.plist key

Tags: ios, xcode, plist

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGCzV.jpg]

[image]

I need to internationalize those tips, but i got this!Any idea?

Comment: if the answer is helpful hope you will accept it too.

Comment: Finally fix! Note:After creating the strings file,you need to include the key in the Info.plist file as well, and the value you can write anything you like but not $(xxxx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to internationalize tips here is the good [Stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25736915/3172726)

**in short** after adding **info.plist** string file for respective language, you can localize just like this.Add your respective permisstion key with appropriate description.

NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription = "请打开【定位服务】允许 Your App 确定您的位置。";

Comment: Finally fix! Note:After creating the strings file,you need to include the key in the Info.plist file as well, and the value you can write anything you like but not $(xxxx)

Answer (score 1):

I also face this type of error.
I think you can describe the message like this.[image]

I think it's help for you.

You should use `InfoPlist.strings` file to localize values of `Info.plist`. To do this, go to `File->New->File`, choose Strings File under Resource tab of iOS, name it `InfoPlist`, and create. Open and insert the `Info.plist` values you want to localize like:

```
"NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription" = "Description of this";
```

**EDIT:**

select the localization options, or enable localization if needed,

[image]

you should be able to see the file also on the left side editor.

[image]

Comment: But i need to internationalize those tips(English&Chinese)

Comment: Info.plist conversation of localization according to languages.and adding message of localization info.plist file.

Comment: I did as you said.And got this message from Apple.

Comment: I just update my answer as you can see. please try to do it.