# Localize app name on the app store by country

Tags: ios, localization, app-store

I have an application on the app store.

I need different app stores to show different names for the app and even different icons if possible - by country **NOT** by language.

For example - England, USA, Canada (all english speaking countries) should all show different names and icons on their app stores. So my apps will be called "Travel England", "Travel USA" and "Travel Canada".

So... can it be done? also can it be done for the icons?

Thanks.

Comment: It can be done based on the languages because app will be notified by the language the user chooses from their device but not by country.

Answer (score 0):

You can localize your app name. It is similar to localize permission strings. You will have InfoPlist.strings files.

1. Localize Info.plist file. [How to localise a string inside the iOS info.plist file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25736700/how-to-localise-a-string-inside-the-ios-info-plist-file)
2. Add ""CFBundleDisplayName" = "My localized app name";" to the corresponding .strings file.

Comment: This is localization by language NOT by country :/

Comment: @ozd When you localize the plist file, can't you optionally do it by language OR country?