# Text on alert view that appear when ask permission for the camera in different lenguajes

Tags: objective-c, permissions, camera, uialertview

APPLE SAID THAT

NSCameraUsageDescription

NSCameraUsageDescription (String - iOS) describes the reason that the app (including an iMessage app) accesses the device’s camera. When the system prompts the user to allow access, this string is displayed as part of the alert.

Important: To protect user privacy, an iOS app linked on or after iOS 10.0, and that accesses the device’s camera, must statically declare the intent to do so. Include the NSCameraUsageDescription key in your app’s Info.plist file and provide a purpose string for this key. If your app attempts to access the device’s camera without a corresponding purpose string, your app exits.

No problem for one lenguaje, but I need this message in english an spanish. What I have to do?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to localise a string inside the iOS info.plist file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25736700/how-to-localise-a-string-inside-the-ios-info-plist-file)

Answer (score 0):

Use localisation for this.For how to localise app for multiple language visit following link for guide:
[Localisation in iOS app](https://www.ibabbleon.com/iphone_app_localization.html)