# InfoPlist.strings on a framework project

Tags: ios, xcode, info.plist

I've created a framework and in this framework the camera usage permission is required. I put the key NSCameraUsageDescription and its translation under my framework project, but my main app project override the translation of the framework project, although the permission is required from a framework function. How I can set a translation of NSCameraUsageDescription specific for my framework project?

- Main app project

  - Info.plist
  - InfoPlist.strings (spanish)  -> "Always this is used"
- Framework project

  - Info.plist
  - InfoPlist.strings (spanish)

Comment: This is a default flow you need to do some work around.

Comment: I believe this has been answered already. Check out [This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25736700/how-to-localise-a-string-inside-the-ios-info-plist-file)

Comment: @Jake, in this link explains how to localize a main app project, and this is working in my project but I need specific translation for the library/framework project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible. iOS grabs the usage description from the main bundle's info plist. The only way to change the usage description is to change `NSCameraUsageDescription` for the "Main app".