# Internationalise Authorisation Sentence in XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, internationalization

I want to internationalise the comment used to give more details about a required authorisation.
My whole project already use a `Localizable.strings` and everything works fine.

But I can't get to make it works with these sentences located here:

[image: The place where the sentence to internationalise]

Am I missing something here? I already tried to add a simple word, that is translated in the `Localizable.strings` but no effects on it so far :(

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25736700/how-to-localise-a-string-inside-the-ios-info-plist-file

Comment: couldn't find it because of wrong keywords.. thanks

Comment: Actually nothing's working for me there :( the solutions are not update to date anymore. I'll create an answer once I figured out how to fix that.