# how to add comments for translator in InfoPlist.strings

Tags: ios, xcode, plist, info-plist

i have in the file **en.lproj\InfoPlist.strings** this content :

```
NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription = "We'll only use your location to find people around you";
NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription = "We'll only use your location to find people you've bumped into";
NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription = "We'll only use your location to find people around you and people you've bumped into";
NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription = "To share photos, we need access to your photo library.";
```

Now the question, how can i add inside this file also comments for the translator ?

Comment: Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25736700/how-to-localise-a-string-inside-the-ios-info-plist-file

Comment: thanks @PratikSodha but their is absolutly nothing about how to add comments  in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25736700/how-to-localise-a-string-inside-the-ios-info-plist-file :(