# How to localize app name shown in launcher using flutter?

Tags: android, dart, flutter

how to localize app name shown in the launcher?

For example, "Play Store", in Chinese is "Play 商店".
Thanks.

I tried to modify `android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml` like this:

```
android:label="@string/app_name"
```

And create files

```
values-zh/strings.xml
values-en/strings.xml
```

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">App name in different language</string>
</resources>
```

But, the app name changes only when the system language changed.
Is this a common problem (or known bug?) in Android?

In windows, when the app language changes, the app name will change immediately.

So, what I really want is, when the language changes in my app, the app name in the launcher will also change, ignoring the system language.

[image]

Answer (score 13):

### Here is the recipe to localize (Internationalize) Launcher App Name in Flutter

##### For Android:

1. Navigate to the following path: `android\app\src\main\res`
2. You should find a folder called `values` if it does not exist, create one, this folder would be for the default locale (language).
3. Add a file named `strings.xml` inside the `values` folder with the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="appName">your_app_name</string>
</resources>
```

**NOTE:** If the file already exists, then just add the `appName` key to it which is just this line:

```
<string name="appName">your_app_name</string>
```

4. Change the value of the key `appName` with your app name for the default locale (language).
5. Copy the `values` folder and its contained `strings.xml` file for each locale, for example if your default locale is `English (en)` and you want to add `Arabic (ar)` and `Spanish (es)` then you will have the following folder structure for the `res` folder:

```
├─── ...
├───values
│   ├─── ...
│   ├─── strings.xml
│   └─── ...
├───values-ar
│   ├─── ...
│   ├─── strings.xml
│   └─── ...
├───values-es
│   ├─── ...
│   ├─── strings.xml
│   └─── ...
└─── ...
```

**NOTE:** You don't have to copy all the keys and values inside the `strings.xml` file, if you have another keys that you don't want to localize them, then you can ignore them for each locale and just include the keys you want to localize, e.g. in this case `appName`.

6. For each locale, go to its `values` folder and change the value of the key `appName` inside the `strings.xml` file.
7. Naviagte to `AndroidManifest` file in the following path: `android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml` and change the value of `android:label` inside the `application` tag to be `android:label="@string/appName"`.
8. Done

---

##### For IOS:

1. Do all the steps in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25736915/11217945).
2. The only key that you would have to localize is `CFBundleName` which is the launcher name of the app.
3. Done

Answer (score 10):

On Android application's `android:label` in `AndroidManifest.xml` is a fixed resource referrer and it's bind to the system language.

So as you saw you can use only configuration qualifier names (values-en, -zh, -large, -land, etc.), according to [Providing Alternative Resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources).

Answer (score 1):

Your original question helped answer my question [Is Internationalize Flutter app name possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72157470/is-internationalize-flutter-app-name-possible)

I just want to document for anyone else that at least for me, putting English `strings.xml` under `res\values-en` folder resulted in compile error, so I moved it to under `res\values` (there is already a styles.xml), and that worked fine. `values-en` as a folder seems unexpected by the system and redundant since the default language is English.

Answer (score 0):

if an error occurred

---

add  `<string name="app_name">default language</string>` in android\app\src\main\res\values\styles.xml

---

maybe lack a default value

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).