# Localize iOS Info.plist Privacy Strings

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, dart

I want to localize the privacy strings from the Runner's info.plist file, but fail to find how. In the official documentation (https://flutter.dev/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization) at the very end is stated to add a key named "*eLocalizations**", but I don't see that if I try to add some new key to the plist (having the top item selected like written in the docs).

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Please see attached what I see in Xcode when I add a new key.

[image]

Comment: Duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25736700/how-to-localise-a-string-inside-the-ios-info-plist-file

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way is to create an `InfoPlist.strings` file and localize that. The Info.plist will pull the appropriate translation from these files.

[image]

Comment: I have created the InfoPlist.strings file. But how do I add a language to it?

Comment: @SimpleUXApps You click on "Runner" in the very top left which takes you to the project settings. Then you click on the little "+" under the "Localizations" section. That gives you a dropdown with all the languages you can add. 