# AppTrackingTransparency - permission already added but still facing error

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios14, apptrackingtransparency

Error : This app has crashed because it attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description.  The app's Info.plist must contain an NSUserTrackingUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

I alread added the permission in .plist

`<key>NSUserTrackingUsageDescription</key>  <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) will track your data</string>`

Comment: Does the crash occur when you request app tracking permission? Are you sure your updated info.plist is making it into your ipa? Also, read the notes [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nsusertrackingusagedescription) - your message should not include your app name.  The text you have provided is also unlikely to pass app review

Comment: I follow all the steps, permission is already added into info.plist but still facing the same crash

Comment: So you have unzipped the ipa that is being installed and verified that the right key is in the info.plist? Show the code that triggers the crash

Comment: I had the same problem with old version of an app. Try to put your 
    <key>NSUserTrackingUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This identifier will be used to deliver personalized ads to you</string> by selecting the project -> target -> info   it's just before Build Settings

Answer (score 1):

The issue in my project was that I had localization for info.plist set up in a wrong way.

For having the values properly localized, add the following `.strings` file and add them there:

[image: Screenshot of localized InfoPlist.strings file]

Make sure to actually call them `InfoPlist.strings` (exactly capitalized like that with capital `I` and `P`)

See also this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25736915/1898677