# How to get a value from InfoPlist.string at runtime?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, plist, info-plist

In `Project/SupportingFiles/en.lproj/InfoPlist.strings` I have this value:

> NSUserTrackingUsageDescription = "dummy";

It's a **localized** `InfoPlist.strings` file, it can be in various languages. In this case, the folder `en.lproj` is for English.

For example, imagine that before compiling I can writte to `NSUserTrackingUsageDescription` a value, and I need to ensure if it's "dummy" at runtime.

It is possible to check in Swift if `NSUserTrackingUsageDescription` is "dummy" or another string at runtime with Swift?

I'm doing a research but I can't find any Swift code to check that.

### Edit

I tried with this code:

```
let string = Bundle.main.infoDictionary!["NSUserTrackingUsageDescription"] as! String
    
if (string == "dummy"){
     logger.debug("NSUserTrackingUsageDescription is dummy")
}else{
     logger.debug("NSUserTrackingUsageDescription is \(string)")
}
```

But it's not working because it enters the else and prints this:

> LauncherViewController.requestAppTrackingTransparencyPermission():131
>
> - NSUserTrackingUsageDescription is dummy, replaced with translation from InfoPlist.strings

I don't know why the system is adding `, replaced with translation from InfoPlist.strings` to `dummy`.

Comment: Search your code base for "replaced with translation from" . Specifically, maybe this suffix is added by the "logger" class for some reason

Comment: "NSUserTrackingUsageDescription can have multiple values", are you sure about this?

Comment: Do you have multiple values added in this Plist for "NSUserTrackingUsageDescription" ?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I mean that i need to know dinamically that value. If i'm executing a project with dummy there, i wanna read dummy there.

Comment: @ManuRaphy read my previous comment

Comment: when i used your code and used print to output the log data , its working as expected . can you check that

Comment: @ManuRaphy Did you have the file localized in various languages? Is the file stored in english in folder en.lproj?

Comment: But a given project (app) will only have one value or none, right? So instead of adding value “dummy” you shouldn’t have that key/value pair at all if it isn’t supported.

Comment: @NullPointerException - do you get the same output using `print(string)` instead of your `logger.debug(...)`?

Comment: May checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25736700/how-to-localise-a-string-inside-the-ios-info-plist-file

Comment: @DonMag using print the output it's the same, also with that rare string

Comment: @JoakimDanielson how to check at runtime if a value inside InfoPlist.strings exists?

Comment: Bundle.main.infoDictionary returns an optional as can be seen in your own code.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson do you have any idea about how to get that value without that extra text?

Comment: @NullPointerException - try it like this: `guard let string = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "NSUserTrackingUsageDescription") as? String else { fatalError("not found") }` ... should give you the *localized* string.

Comment: @DonMag please, open an answer, I will accept it, it works perfectly

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Best approach is to use:

```
guard let string = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "NSUserTrackingUsageDescription") as? String 
    else { fatalError("not found") }
```

Note from Apple's [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/bundle/1408696-object):

> Use of this method is preferred over other access methods because it returns the localized value of a key when one is available.