# iOS Change Title of NSUserTrackingUsageDescription

Tags: ios, swift

How can I customize the title of the NSUserTrackingUsageDescription system prompt / alert?

In the attached image I underlined the text I want to change with color green.

The text underlined with yellow can be customized within Info.plist key "Privacy - Tracking Usage Description", that works fine.

Maybe this can be done with localization?

[image: alert to customize]

Comment: That text cannot be changed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Paulw11. Why cant it be changed? Is there an Apple guideline or something similar which states that?

Comment: There just isn't any API or way to change it.  The dialog is presented by iOS. You can't change the titles of any system "permission" dialogs. It is a user protection. Unscrupulous app creators could try to do sneaky things.  Consistency also helps users understand what is being requested.

Comment: Yes, You can localize info.plist file messages. https://stackoverflow.com/a/25736915/1597744

Comment: @ToseefKhilji it is not available within the info.plist, so no localization is available

Comment: @PaulVincentBeigang: You need to create new file `InfoPlist.strings` that will contain localize strings.

Comment: @ToseefKhilji what key to use in "InfoPlist.strings" to localize the specific prompt title I want to change?

Comment: @PaulVincentBeigang: Please check this [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009254-102276) and this SA question https://stackoverflow.com/q/25736700/1597744

Answer (score 0):

It can´t be changed, there is no API available.

See @Paulw11 comments to the original question.