# Unable to localise a string inside the iOS info.plist file

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, localization, info-plist

In my app, I want to support localization. I able to localise app using `Localizable.strings` except for Info.plist file. I want to localise app's privacy alert messages. I found below helpful links but it is not working with `Xcode 9.4.1` and `iOS 11+`.

I followed the same steps:

1. Created `InfoPlist.strings`
2. Localised this file for selected languages
3. And added keys and values as : `Key = "value";` in this `InfoPlist.strings` file

   eg. `NSContactsUsageDescription = "App use Contacts to select contacts";`
4. Also found this file in `"Project settings" -> "Build Phases" -> "Copy Bundle Resources"`

Found some blogs/information as:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/25736915/1635315
- [Apple developer site](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LocalizingYourApp/LocalizingYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171i-CH5-SW21)
- https://burcugeneci.wordpress.com/2015/11/19/can-you-localize-your-info-plist/
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/26059896/1635315

Any idea how to do with `Xcode 9.4.1` and `iOS 11+`?

Comment: Do you have quotes around your keys? The example above shows `NSContactsUsageDescription = "App...` but you really want it to be `"NSContactsUsageDescription" = "App...`

Comment: I tried with double quotes but not worked

Comment: Do you have the keys in your `Info.plist` file as well? I think you have to have the key in there with just the default translation as the value in order for it to pick up the translated values in the `InfoPlist.strings` file.

Comment: @Stonz2, Yes I have `Info.plist` file with these keys and its values in the English language.

Answer (score 1):

Hai please refer the image shown  below

[image: The info.plist]

check with the localization which you provided

Comment: Are you localising Info.plist file? I did that before it is creating `Info.plist (English)` and `Info.plist (Japanese)` instead `InfoPlist.strings` file.